# Remove products from all categories when price is zero

Tags: magento-1.9, category-products

For SEO reasons I want to keep products which are not being produced anymore on my website, so I edited some stuff so when I change the price of the products to 0,-. It displays a text that the product is unavailable, and it removes the 'add to cart' button.

Now I would like to remove them from all the categories they're in, and preferably also put them in a new category called 'Old models' (ID=863).

I don't really code myself but I found some parts and put them together.

What I have now:

```
// get products price 0        
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
    umask(0);
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID); 
    Mage::app();
    $Products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter(
      array(
         array('attribute'=>'price', 'eq'=>'0'),
         array('attribute'=>'price', 'isnull'=>true),
      )
);

   // remove categories

    foreach($Products as $product){
       Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')->removeProduct($category->getId(),$p‌​roduct->getId());
    }

  // add category
foreach($Products as $product){
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `setCategoryIds()` product function you will no longer have to use the `removeProduct()` category function since it overwrites all previous set category IDs.

Try the following script:

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');

umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID); 
Mage::app();
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        array(
            array('attribute'=>'price', 'eq'=>'0'),
            array('attribute'=>'price', 'isnull'=>true),
        )
);

$category_id = 863; // "Old models" category ID.

foreach($products as $product) {
    $product->setCategoryIds([$category_id]);
    $product->save();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the solution! Unfortunately I'm getting a HTTP 500 error. Any idea why that is?

Comment: Try adding
```error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);```
to the top of your script to see what is causing this error.

Comment: Hmm I tried but it doesn't show any. Chrome just shows the http 500 error, while Firefox and Safari just show a blank page. I ran some other php scripts I have (like one rearranging categories in alphabetical order) and they are working fine.

Comment: Try adding `var_dump($products);` under the `$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')` function and see if that returns anything.

Comment: Same thing, just the http 500 error.. I removed the () around 'app/Mage.php' as I saw that it's without those in the other scripts. But that didn't do anything either.

Comment: Changed the name of .htaccess, tried to add ini_set("memory_limit","1024M");. Both didn't work

Comment: There must be something wrong with the script, I added it below another one and then it gives a HTTP 500 error as well

Comment: I did notice I made a single closing ] bracket error. Which has now been edited