# HTTP 500 error with a php script

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, http-error-500

The following piece of code provided by SuperDicq [Remove products from all categories when price is zero](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/265725/remove-products-from-all-categories-when-price-is-zero)) gives me a HTTP 500 error, anyone knows what's wrong?

I changed the name of htaccess, put memory limit on 1024mb. I have other scripts which are causing no problems. Also when I add this one below they start giving errors as well.

```
  require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
Mage::app();
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        array(
            array('attribute'=>'price', 'eq'=>'0'),
            array('attribute'=>'price', 'isnull'=>true),
        )
);
$category_id = 863; // "Old models" category ID.
foreach($products as $product) {
    $product->setCategoryIds($category_id);
    $product->save();
}
```

Comment: Is this script on your magento root ?

Comment: Isn't there anything in your log files? 500 server errors could also imply errors on your webserver (httpd/nginx), so it would make sense to check those as well besides your Magento log files.

Comment: Yes it's in the root. Can't find any error in the logs when I turn error reporting on

Answer (score 1):

HTTP 500 Error can occur due to the file permission also..i have the same issue today..

check that the file have proper file permission..

php file need a 644 permission..

please try this..

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately it's already on 644 :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found out that, in my case it was due to large sets of data.

Ended up adding:

->setPageSize(X)
->setCurPage(1);

To the collection. I simply started by adding a small number to setPageSize() eg. X = 100 and then slowlyg worked my way up till I found a higher number, that didn't cause error 500.

It might be some settings that needs to be changed, but for now this can resolve the issue.